# Get alert if Alamofire request is failed

Tags: swift, request, alamofire

i am using Alamofire, SwiftyJSON to get data, but i can not understand how do i use error alert in ViewConroller, so my code here..

```
class Networking {
    
    static func FetchData() {
        
        AF.request("https://ApiApiApiApi", method: .get).validate().responseJSON { responseJSON -> Void in
            
            switch responseJSON.result {
            case .success:
                print("Validation Successful")
            case .failure(let error):
                // Here i need to show alert in viewController
                print("\(error)")
            }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If i got error i need to show alert in the ViewContoller

```
class ViewContoller: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        Networking.FetchData()
    }

}
```

Comment: Add a completion handler or use async/await. And forget SwiftyJSON, decode the data directly into a model with `responseDecodable`. `responseJSON` is deprecated anyway in AF 5.6+

Comment: Could u give me a code example of using responseDecodable and completion handler in case .error, please?

Comment: For the completion handler please [search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Balamofire%5D+completion) and without knowing the JSON it's impossible to suggest something.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you can create an enum for error messages.

```
enum YourErrorMessage: String, Error {
   case failed = "There is an error"
}
```

And then add a completion handler to your method.

```
class Networking {
    
    static func FetchData(completion: @escaping(YourErrorMessage) -> Void) {
        
        AF.request("https://ApiApiApiApi", method: .get).validate().responseJSON { responseJSON -> Void in
            
            switch responseJSON.result {
                case .success:
                    print("Validation Successful")
                case .failure(let error):
                    completion(.failed)
                    print("\(error)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can reach the method state(failure, success).

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        Networking.FetchData { errorMessage in
            print(errorMessage.rawValue)
        }
    }
}
```